# iPhone app using .NET development environment?

Tags: iphone

How could I create iPhone applications using the .NET development environment?

Answer (score 18):

The Mono team are working on 'static compilation' which allows mono apps to be run on a non-jailbroken iPhone.  In short this works by running a cross-compiling JIT step as part of the build process to generate a native exe.

There was a demo of this at the PDC ... see [Miguel de Icaza](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-05.html)'s blog.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is MonoTouch From Novell - http://www.mono-project.com/MonoTouch. Beta version will be released on August 2009 and commercial released will be on September 2009.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to leverage some knowledge of c#, you can use Unity. Games developed with Unity (http://unity3d.com) use Mono with an AOT (ahead-of-time compiler) to compile mono bytecodes to ARM. (The apps created by Unity have a shell that is, in fact, a fairly conventional cocoa touch app created in Objective-C++ and XCode.) It's not a dot net app, but you can use your existing knowledge of c#.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.  You need Xcode on Mac OS X to write iPhone applications.

---

Update: 9-20-2009

This was once true.  See comments below for more info.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Apple does not support the Microsoft .Net development environment.

At most you could hope for is installing [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) on a [jailbroken](http://www.iphonehacks.com/jailbreak_iphone/) iphone. Not that I condone this and you do so at your own risk.

IPhone applications are developed using Objective C or Ruby.

Comment: Hey Xian - got a link for using Ruby on the iphone?? i hadn't heard of that.

Comment: I think I was getting ahead if myself when I said that (was thinking of mac development with RubyCocoa), but I have heard that a guys called Takuma may have cracked it http://wiki.github.com/takuma104/iphone-rubycocoa

Answer (score 1):

The only supported way to develop native iPhone applications is the iPhone SDK.  It runs on Mac OS X only, and supports development using the Cocoa Touch frameworks and the Objective-C 2.0 language.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get other languages to work, they will - however - almost certainly not be accepted to the AppStore and will break with future updates.  Generally it is better to use a screw driver to screw something into a hole than to thwap it repeated with a hammer attached to a 250hp motor...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Third party Tool called Component Studio - iPhone . More info please [see this](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/StudioiPhone/)